# Can I choose which state to pay income tax to when I am traveling and have no permanent residence in the US?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, travel

I am leaving for a year-long trip around the world. I will have an income while traveling. Is it possible for me to choose which state will tax me as I will not have a permanent residence in any state? My current state has a flat income tax rate of 5% and I know some states that have a 0% income tax rate. I would like to pay taxes to one of those states, preferably Washington. How can I do this?

Comment: What state are you in and what state is your employer in?

Comment: We are both in Utah

Comment: The simple answer here is "No".  They thought of that  :)

Comment: I think that If I have no house or car here I don’t have to pay income tax as I will not considered to have a domicile. I believe it is possible to not pay income taxes to any state while I am away.

Answer (score 3):

You should consult a tax professional who specializes in Utah personal income tax. In short no, you can't choose what state to be a resident of.

The Utah State Tax Commission says "[Anyone with a Utah domicile is considered a Utah resident for tax purposes, even if they are not currently living in Utah.](https://incometax.utah.gov/instructions/residency-and-domicile#domicile)"
There are two ways to get rid of your Utah tax liability:

1. Become a genuine resident of another state

or

2. You (and your spouse) "[are absent from Utah for at least 761 consecutive days](https://incometax.utah.gov/instructions/residency-and-domicile#nodomicile)" do not return to Utah for more than 30 days in a calendar year, and other requirements.

To become a resident of most states they require that you have an intent to move their long term. Washington State you must "[take some action that proves you intend to live in the state on more than a temporary or transient basis.](https://access.wa.gov/topics/living/becomeresident.html)

FYI Utah says "You must file a Utah income tax return (or amended return) and pay any penalty and interest that apply if you did not file a Utah return based upon your belief that you did not meet the domicile criteria."

Unless you inteneed to move to another state after your time traveling